Flutter WEB: Native web search
I have developed a web application using Flutter-Web. Client wants to be able to search inside the flutter's page with the native web search (sc: CTRL+F).
Is there any solution that when a user opens the native search and start typing, it renders the UI and highlights the text?

This is still an opened unresolved issue.
As a hack, you can run/build your app with:
--web-renderer html


But it doesn't work well, especially if searching for more than one word at a time:

